# Move the Run Text property to the content of the element

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, richtextbox, linq-to-xml

How could you move Run's Text property to the content of the Run tag. e.g.

```
string str = "<Run Text='hello world' />";

//into

string str2 = "<Run>hello world</Run>";
```

Bearing in mind that the string could contain several Paragraphs and multiple Runs (I want all Runs altered). Ideally I want to keep it as a string rather than converting to XML or XAML so maybe a Regex statement?. If not then I will accept converting it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from @ionden:

```
string str = "<Para> <Run Text='hello world' /> <Run Text='goodbye world' /></Para>";
XElement elem = XElement.Parse(str);

var runs = elem.DescendantsAndSelf("Run");

foreach (var run in runs)
{
    // modify in-place to preserve the (unknown) structure. 
    run.Value = run.Attribute("Text").Value;
    run.Attribute("Text").Remove();
}

str = elem.ToString();
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get the DescendantsAndSelf("Run") to work correctly. Without the "Run" it works (a mixture of Runs and Paragraphs) but with it it returns nothing...

Comment: Just tested it, works OK. List some more testcases in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 XElement elem = XElement.Parse(str);
 string str2 = new XElement(elem.Name, elem.Attribute("Text").Value).ToString();
```

Comment: Nice start but you'll have to iterate/recurse over all Runs.

Comment: @Henk yes indeed it was just an idea

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "<Root><Run Text='hello world' /><Run Text='hello world2' /></Root>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(str);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("Root/Run");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    XmlAttribute attr = node.Attributes["Text"];
    node.InnerText = attr.Value.ToString();
    node.Attributes.Remove(attr);                
}
str = doc.InnerXml;
```